# Removing Empathy from 12.10 wants to remove the Gnome-Core package

Tags: 12.10, empathy, dependencies

I would like to remove Empathy from my Ubuntu system, (I am currently running Quantal without Unity, just Gnome). When I try remove it in Synaptic it also wants to remove Gnome-Core, which I assume will break my setup.

Am I correct?

Comment: I have the same problem with removing EDS. I think the dependencies may need looking at. You may try filing a bug at launchpad.

Answer (score 6):

No you are **not** correct.

Removing `gnome-core` **will not** break your system.

**gnome-core** is in fact a *meta-package*, have a look at this url for adidtional information on the gnome-core package: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gnome-core

Info on *meta-packages*: 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages

You can safely uninstall Empathy and the gnome-core meta package.

milo

Answer (score 0):

I believe gnome-core is a meta-package. It just makes sure certain things get installed. I don't believe removing it will remove anything else.