# Uninstall empathy without affecting dependencies

Tags: gnome, uninstall, empathy

I am trying to uninstall empathy from my Ubuntu 12.10. So I issued the following command

```
sudo apt-get purge empathy
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:

  account-plugin-identica account-plugin-twitter gir1.2-messagingmenu-1.0

Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.

The following packages will be REMOVED:

  account-plugin-aim* account-plugin-jabber* account-plugin-salut* account-plugin-yahoo* empathy* **gnome* gnome-core*** mcp-account-manager-uoa* nautilus-sendto-empathy*

0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 9 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

After this operation, 8,664 kB disk space will be freed.

Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

It is trying to remove gnome and gnome-core by default. Will it really uninstall gnome as well? How do I uninstall empathy without affecting gnome?

EDIT: As suggested by vasa1 in the comments, I tried marking the packages as manual using

> sudo apt-mark manual gnome gnome-core

That also didnt help.

Comment: BTW, what do you see when you run `dpkg --get-selections | grep gnome` because I just noticed it wants to remove `gnome*`?

Comment: The list is too big to post here... https://gist.github.com/thefourtheye/5325938

Comment: There are a couple of older questions where such a problem of removing gnome* and gnome-core* wasn't reported: http://askubuntu.com/q/93266/25656 and http://askubuntu.com/q/62664/25656. I don't know whether something has changed with 12.10.

Comment: Yup... In my machine, it says it will remove gnome and gnome-core :(

Comment: Okay, I'll delete my answer but all the best. Maybe you can just leave empathy installed?

Comment: BTW, did you try `sudo apt-mark manual gnome gnome-core` or `sudo apt-mark manual gnome* gnome-core*`?

Comment: I tried without * marks.

Answer (score 1):

If, as appears to be the case, `gnome` and `gnome-core` depend on `empathy` (or some other package that depends on it), even if you manage to uninstall `empathy` without removing packages that depend on it, whatever depends on it *won't work* and you'll (in this case) wind up with a system that, at best, will boot to a command line.  It may not even complete booting to a text login prompt, depending on what else depends on `empathy`, through whatever length chain.

Answer (score -1):

Open synaptic package manager and type empathy in the search box and remove that single package.

Vasa1 gave us CLI way and I am giving GUI way .

Comment: It still warns me about removing gnome and gnome-core

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/223034/removing-empathy-from-12-10-wants-to-remove-the-gnome-core-package

Not a problem

Comment: @Jai, but that one only deals with gnome-core. This one has gnome* **and** gnome-core*.

Comment: Synaptic removes dependent packages the same way apt does -- in fact, Synaptic acts, in part, as a front end for apt.